# Fetching database query results HQL

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am running a login script that queries a database for a valid user name/hash pair. The code is as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean login(User user) {
    // Check if we have a valid user/pass pair
    Query query = (Query) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username=:userName AND u.password=:password");
    ((javax.persistence.Query) query).setParameter("userName", user.getUsername());
    // We need to hash the password first before comparing it(as we only store the SHA-512 hash)
    String tohash = user.getPassword();
    String hash = null;
    try {
        // Create MessageDigest instance for MD5
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        // Add password bytes to digest
        md.update(tohash.getBytes());
        // Get the hash's bytes
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
        // This bytes[] has bytes in decimal format;
        // Convert it to hexadecimal format
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100,
                    16).substring(1));
        }
        // Get complete hashed password in hex format
        hash = sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ((javax.persistence.Query) query).setParameter("password", hash);
    List<User> users = castList(User.class, ((javax.persistence.Query) query).getResultList());
    if(users != null && !users.isEmpty()) {
        // return "Welcome " + user.getUsername() + "!";
        return true;
    } else {
        // return "Username or password are not valid";
        return false;
    }
}
```

where **castList** is used to specify the types of elements in the list(getting the list by default results in an undefined type warning). The code is bellow:

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Class<? extends T> clazz, Collection<?> c) {
        List<T> r = new ArrayList<T>(c.size());
        for(Object o: c)
          r.add(clazz.cast(o));
        return r;
    }
```

The method above always returns true even if the table is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: The table is probably not empty. Or it is, but the code targets another database than the one you're looking at. That said, all those useless casts, nulll checks and copies make your code much harder to read than it should. And the hashing part should be in a separate method.

Comment: I have a separate client connected the database; the table is empty and the database in use is the right one(I can insert values). The problem arises when the table is empty and I launch that query. How can I check whether the query succeeded or not?

Comment: Make sure you commit after you delete everything in the table. If the table was empty, the query wouldn't return anything. You could print the result list (or examine its content using your debugger) to have more details. Also, see https://gist.github.com/jnizet/8924228 for a more readable (and efficient, and correct) version of your code.

Comment: I'm just wondering doesn't return !users.isEmpty(); throw a NULL pointer exception in case users is null?

Comment: users will never be null. getResultList() will always return a non-null list, or throw an exception. That's a good practice your own code should also follow: if a method returns a collection, it should never return null. Returning an empty collection is the right thing to do if nothing must be returned, because the caller doesn't have to check for null, and can iterate without fearing an NPE.